# Overwatch game stats question incorrectly closed as off topic

Tags: discussion, closing

I asked [Where does Master Overwatch get its data from?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/271296/where-does-master-overwatch-get-its-stats-from), which was incorrectly closed as off topic. The mods assumed it was about game design or development, but Master Overwatch is not a game designer or developer. They do not make games. They are an Overwatch stats website.

I then asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/271331/) and deleted all references to Blizzard, development, and APIs to avoid confusion. It was closed as a duplicate of the first.

For reference, here is the [on-topic FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

A commenter suggest I appeal here, so here I am. (My typing is terse because I'm on a phone.)

Comment: rolling back. Im not sure how the system even allowed editing "the question" to "the question",  but honestly, should know better

Comment: @Timelord64 So linking to the question is wrong?  Rather than the comment?  Seriously?

Comment: @Frank, the edit summary literally shows changes (or in this case, no actual changes) to the text. There was nothing there about links

Comment: @Timelord64 the edit itself shows what was changed it you look at the markup version, not the rendered output. Furthermore, Frank explained *exactly* what he did on the summary. A link to the question rather than a comment on the question is preferable here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with the close.  The wording of the close reason doesn't exactly match your question, but the reasoning for why it was created in the first place still applies.

Basically, you're asking a question that only the developer of the software can answer.  That's why the close reason is there; it's to prevent speculative answers.  In this case, it doesn't matter that the software is a utility, not a game, you're still asking about software design and development.

Comment: As a sidenote, since you haven't found any evidence for an API for Overwatch stats, I'm guessing that he's scraping the information from playoverwatch.com profile pages.  See?  Speculation.

Comment: This makes for a frustrating procedure to finely hone a wording that won't get the question closed. I don't really care where Master Overwatch gets its data from exactly, I just want to know where I can get comprehensive Overwatch data of the kind Master Overwatch seems to have. I will ask that question and maybe it won't get closed, but why should the barrier to entry be so frustratingly high? This is a videogame fan website.

Comment: @DavidS yes, it is a gaming fan website, but unlike some others, we prefer a certain subset of questions and a reasonable language usage.

Comment: @DavidS there are many websites about videogames, and this one is a little bit different. I must admit that questions on how to build software that talks to Overwatch -- what else would you use an API for? -- are not obviously in our scope.

Comment: @DavidS You're asking a question that only the developer can answer. If you want to know where to get such information, your best bet is to contact the developer of the Master Overwatch.

Comment: Personally, I would have voted to close with a custom off-topic reason; we don't know how that website was coded, nor is it a game.  How it works doesn't belong here.

Comment: @Frank So would the question then be more at home, perhaps, in Game Development or Stack Overflow itself?  Or perhaos the Web development community?